# Re-sizing form content to fit browser window - Using Card Layout

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1

I need the tab-panels to fit browser window size. I have used `card layout`, and it is not re-sizing to fit the browser window. I think i'm missing some properties in my `viewPort`.

```
launch: function() {                           
        Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {    
            layout: 'card',
            items: [  
            { 
                xtype: 'panel',   
                items: { xtype: 'tabP1' } 
            },
            {
                xtype: 'panel',
                items: { xtype:'tabP2' }
            }                
            ,
            {
                xtype: 'panel',
                items: { xtype:'tabP3' }
            }           
            ]
        }); 
    },
```

2.) One of my tabpanels; I am using `absolute layout`. I am using this layout because it's easy to set form components where i ever i desire it to be. Therefore, i would like a solution that works with the same layout.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyForm', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
     alias:'widget.tabP1',
   // height: 250,
   // width: 726,
 layout: {
    type: 'absolute'
},
    bodyPadding: 10,
    title: 'My Form',

    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;

        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'gridpanel',
                    title: 'My Grid Panel',
                    columns: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                            dataIndex: 'string',
                            text: 'String'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'numbercolumn',
                            dataIndex: 'number',
                            text: 'Number'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'datecolumn',
                            dataIndex: 'date',
                            text: 'Date'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'booleancolumn',
                            dataIndex: 'bool',
                            text: 'Boolean'
                        }
                    ],
                    viewConfig: {

                    }
                }
            ]
        });

        me.callParent(arguments);
    }

});
```

**UPDATE 2**

**UPDATE 2**

```
launch: function() {                           
            Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {    
                layout: 'card',
                items: [  
                { 

                     xtype: 'tabP1'  
                },
                {

                    xtype:'tabP2' 
                }                
                ,
                {

                    xtype:'tabP3' 
                }           
                ]
            }); 
        },


onSuccess: function() {  
     this.getViewport().getLayout().setActiveItem(1); 
    },
```

I get an error when i use your code, saying that `this.getViewport().getLayout().setActiveItem(1)` is not a function. I think this is because i used `border layout`. How can i resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is "over-nesting" Why are you putting 'tabPFoo' inside a panel with no layout? They are at best, redundant, also causing the layout system to spend more cycles when it's not needed.

```
Ext.require('*');

Ext.onReady(function(){

    var vp = new Ext.container.Viewport({
        layout: 'card',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'grid',
            store: {
                fields: ['name'],
                data: [{
                    name: 'Name 1'
                }]
            },
            columns: [{
                flex: 1,
                dataIndex: 'name',
                text: 'Name'
            }],
            listeners: {
                itemclick: function(view){
                    var grid = view.ownerCt,
                        next = grid.nextSibling();

                    vp.getLayout().setActiveItem(next);
                }
            }
        }, {
            xtype: 'grid',
            store: {
                fields: ['name'],
                data: [{
                    name: 'Name 2'
                }]
            },
            columns: [{
                flex: 1,
                dataIndex: 'name',
                text: 'Name'
            }],
            listeners: {
                itemclick: function(view){
                    var grid = view.ownerCt,
                        next = grid.nextSibling();

                    vp.getLayout().setActiveItem(next);
                }
            }
        }, {
            xtype: 'grid',
            store: {
                fields: ['name'],
                data: [{
                    name: 'Name 3'
                }]
            },
            columns: [{
                flex: 1,
                dataIndex: 'name',
                text: 'Name'
            }],
            listeners: {
                itemclick: function(view){
                    var grid = view.ownerCt,
                        next = grid.previousSibling().previousSibling();

                    vp.getLayout().setActiveItem(next);
                }
            }
        }]
    });

});
```

Obviously that's not MVC style, but that's the structure the layout should take.

Comment: When i click on the submit button of `tabP1` and when the `tabP2` loads,  i see a huge white space on top of the page (This white space is equal to the height and width of `tabP1`). I think that `tabP2` is not falling on top of `tabP1`. How can i solve this ?

Comment: I don't know what tabP1/2/3 are, so... I couldn't say.

Comment: I have added the code for `tabP1` above. `tabP2` and `tabP3` are the same as `tabP1`

Comment: The way you're doing it is totally wrong. You're trying to have 3 grids, each one having it's own card right?

Comment: I am having 3 Form panels, and when the user clicks on a row in the first grid (which is in `tabP1`), The 2nd form panel loads on top of it (This form panel has a Grid). And when i click on a row on a Grid of `tabP2` , the 3rd Form Panel loads on top of it. NOTE : There are other components in these form panels textfields, labels etc..

Comment: Yes thank you, But what am i missing in my code, it looks the same. :(

Comment: It's not the same. As I said above, it's over-nesting. Compare the structure.

Comment: I have updated my code above. Please have a look. It looks like what you suggested.

Comment: No, it's not the same. The grids I have are directly in the card layout. You have an absolute layout container with a grid inside.

Comment: Not, only the Gird but there are other components in that Tab Panel. Therefore is there a another method to do this. When i try to replace `Absolute layout` with `Card Layout` i only see the Grid in the whole screen and not the other form components (textfields,labels etc..)

Comment: Yes, there are plenty of examples of putting multiple items in a layout, take some time to read through the documentation.